# How to add a Selection Change Listener to a picker in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to make a picker when only you change the value selected of the picker do something.

Thanks.

**Edit: I answer myself:**

```
picker.addActionListener((ActionListener) (ActionEvent ev) -> {
        doSomething();
    });
```

This code works   d(Ow<)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use something like this:

```
Picker picker = new Picker();
picker.setStrings("one", "two", "three");
picker.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        String selectedValue = picker.getSelectedString();
        if (selectedValue == null) {
            //Cancel pressed
        } else if (previousValue.equals(selectedValue)) {
            // Selected same value
        }else {
            // Selected new value
            doSomething();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Where do you declare "previousValue"?

Comment: you can define previous value as `empty string` (I chose string picker as example) right after picker definition and set it to selected value before `doSomething()`